# How to add facebook share for each product in core php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am facing some issue with Facebook share. I have tried many ways that I found on google but no success. My problem is I have an e-commerce site in core PHP.

> **Every product has its own share button, when I try to share that particular product, it shares site banner instead product image.**

I want to share three dynamic thing:

1. Only the product image no other image
2. Product title
3. Product description

I am using this code I don't understand the concept of url here.

```
         <html>
      <head>

    </head>
   <body>
   <?php
 $title=urlencode('Title of Your iFrame Tab');
 $url=urlencode('http://www.facebook.com/wordpressdesign');
 $summary=urlencode('Custom message that summarizes what your 
  tab is about, or just a simple message to tell people to check out your tab.');
   $image=urlencode('http://www.votebyu.dk/product_images/2014-07-21_43783.jpg');
     ?>
   <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&  amp;p[title]=<?php  echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Insert text or an image here.</a>

  </body>
   </html>
```

This code is not working can any one suggest what the issue ?Do i need to create app for this ?
     what is this here i just copy from google

```
      $url=urlencode('http://www.facebook.com/wordpressdesign');
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can prefer my below answer and then on the click of the share button on the particular image you can just set the value of the image in the og tag with the url of the image being clicked and you are done :)

Comment: Do i need to create app for this

Answer (score 0):

As per facebook privacy rules you need to submit your facebook application for review and you need to provide all information why you want to share on user's feed and how you are going to share it. Facebook review team will review your app and then only you will be able to make this happen. until that you are only able to post from account in which you have created your app. Check with that account and try to share if you have implemented properly it will work with that. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Hope this help :)

Comment: Can you please suggest me step that i need to follow I think i m misisng some part at my end

Comment: open developers.facebook.com and click on Status & Review tab, you will find Start Submission button there click on it and facebook will suggest you steps.

Answer (score 0):

[Sharing on Facebook: How to Improve Your Results by Customizing the Image, Title, and Text](http://rickmanelius.com/article/sharing-facebook-how-improve-your-results-customizing-image-title-and-summary-text#Automatic)

From the link above. For the best possible share, you'll want to suggest 3 pieces of data in your HTML:

```
Title
Short description
Image
```

This accomplished by the following, placed inside the 'head' tag of your HTML:

```
Title: <title>INSERT POST TITLE</title>
Image: <meta property=og:image content="site.com/YOUR_IMAGE.jpg"/>
Description: <meta name=description content="INSERT YOUR SUMMARY TEXT"/>
```

If you website is static HTML, you'll have to do this for every page using your HTML editor.

If you're using a CMS like Drupal, you can automate a lot of it (see above link). If you use wordpress, you can probably implement something similar using the Drupal example as a guideline. I hope you found these useful.

Finally, you can always manually edit your share posts. See this example with illustrations.